# How to compare a value to the values of a column of a dataframe and find the potential rank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe df with four columns looking like this:

```
timestamp values rank compare
   t1       v1    1     c1
   t1       v2    3     c1
   t1       v3    2     c1
   t2       v4    2     c2
   t2       v5    3     c2
   t2       v6    1     c2
   t2       v7    4     c2
```

The values v are measured values at a time t. This values are ranked, s.t. the smallest value is on rank 1 and the largest value on the biggest rank. Additionally I have a value c for every timestamp. Now I want to add an extra column and write the rank c would be if it was a normal value in it.
So the result could be for example:

```
timestamp values rank compare rank_c
   t1       v1    1     c1       2
   t1       v2    3     c1       2
   t1       v3    2     c1       2
   t2       v4    2     c2       1
   t2       v5    3     c2       1
   t2       v6    1     c2       1
   t2       v7    4     c2       1
```

So far I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df_out = pd.DataFrame()
for ts in df['timestamp'].unique(): 
    df_help = df.loc[df['timestamp'] == ts]
    comp = df_help['compare'].iloc[0]
    value_list = list(df_help['values'])
    value_list.append(comp)
    value_list.sort()
    df_help['rank_c'] = value_list.index(comp) + 1
    df_out = df_out.append(df_help, ignore_index = True)
```

It works but is not very fast.
So how can I make it faster?

edit add concrete example:

given dataframe df:

```
timestamp values rank compare
  12:00    0.23    1   0.42
  12:00    0.45    3   0.42
  12:00    0.37    2   0.42
  14:00    0.33    2   0.22
  14:00    0.54    3   0.22
  14:00    0.17    1   0.22
  14:00    0.76    4   0.22
```

Consider first timestamp 12:00:

```
timestamp values rank compare
  12:00    0.23    1   0.42
  12:00    0.45    3   0.42
  12:00    0.37    2   0.42
```

Now I want to find out which rank the value in compare would get if it would be an entry in the values column (it is the same for every row per timestamp). In the concrete example we see that the compare value for the first timestamp would be on the third rank (and the compare value for the second timestamp would be on the second rank).

So the expected output should be:

```
timestamp values rank compare rank_c
  12:00    0.23    1   0.42     3
  12:00    0.45    3   0.42     3
  12:00    0.37    2   0.42     3
  14:00    0.33    2   0.22     2
  14:00    0.54    3   0.22     2
  14:00    0.17    1   0.22     2
  14:00    0.76    4   0.22     2
```

Comment: The values in `rank` are based on the rank within a timestamp, correct? What about the values in `rank_c`? Are they also supposed to be based within a timestamp group? Because the values in `rank_c` seem to be constant for each timestamp grouping

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Because now all data are 1 in sample dataframe in new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is as below:

```
def find_c(gb):
    comp = gb['compare'].iloc[0]
    value_list = gb['values'].tolist()
    value_list.append(comp)
    value_list.sort()
    gb['rank_c'] = value_list.index(comp) + 1
    return gb

df.groupby('timestamp').apply(find_c)
```

Using pandas groupby.apply instead of looping and append items to new list. Not sure how much it would approve, if you can test it and show me the result, it would be awesome.

**New edition:**

@jezrael's idea give me some inspirations. I have updated the function, using np.where to find and set all 'values' that are smaller than 'compare', and then find the total and plus 1 for the result.

```
def find_c(gb):
    gb['rank_c'] = np.where(gb['compare'] > gb['values'], 1, 0).sum()+1
    return gb

df.groupby('timestamp').apply(find_c)
```

This method with np.where is a bit better, it can save up 5% of the time, compared to the method above, and is more pythonic.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is much faster.
My attempt: 232 ms ± 21.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
Yours: 33.9 ms ± 6.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)

for a dataframe with 100 rows

Comment: That's great. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract columns and count how many values is below `0` by `sum` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['compare'] = (df['values'].sub(df['compare']).le(0)
                             .groupby(df['timestamp'])         
                             .transform('sum')
                             .add(1)
                             .astype(int))
print (df)
  timestamp  values  rank  compare
0     12:00    0.23     1        3
1     12:00    0.45     3        3
2     12:00    0.37     2        3
3     14:00    0.33     2        2
4     14:00    0.54     3        2
5     14:00    0.17     1        2
6     14:00    0.76     4        2
```

Comment: I like the idea (and tried something similar), but it is a bit slower than @Shengs method.

38.3 ms ± 5.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 10 loops each) compared to
33.9 ms ± 6.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: You are right, but the dataframe I used is much bigger than the test df for timing

Comment: @Philipp - Ok, no problem ;)